# ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219 NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 15.04 and after installing the latest nvidia drivers (346.59) which worked on ubuntu 14.10 seems to have caused some trouble on boot.

All I get is the following when booting:

- A purple screen for about a second and then

  ```
  [0.514409] ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219
  ```
- A black screen with a message of my monitor saying : No Signal detected.

I am using a GTX 970.

Comment: I had a similar problem after a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 install with a GTX960M. When I chose in the "Additional drivers menu" to use the proprietary drivers for Nvidia and used "nomodeset" in my Grub line, it happened that I could boot after the ACPI message, but then at the graphical login screen when entering my password, nothing happened. The tty screens where also not appearing, just a small purple line at the top. Then I restarted in recovery mode, fixed packages and started with the failsafeX mode and suddenly now it works. I don't know really what I did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me, two solutions worked:

1. Use the X.Org Nouveau display driver (by purging the Nvidia binary drivers as described in other answers). The drawback is that it will impact the graphics performance which is better with an official Nvidia driver.
2. Install the Nvidia driver and boot with the 'nomodeset' flag. To do this, configure Grub as described in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383636/12-04-3-can-start-only-after-press-resume-in-rescue-mode-every-boot-proble)

This will show a really ugly splash screen during booting, but once you passed it you reach sddm and have a nice graphics performance.

Comment: nomodeset works really well like charm!

Comment: Hey looks like the problem is back after a update :(

Comment: works perfectly! How does it impact the normal boot? Do i have to compensate any other thing? I am asking so late, but please try to help me.. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

From the looks of it, nobody's mentioned how this **is** filed as a bug?! o.0

Have a look @https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1432171

Answer (score 3):

I seemed to have fixed it but I still am not very satisfied since I had to uninstall the `nvidia-346` drivers. I hope 15.04 will fix this issue. Else all works again. Thanks to Tim for helping me as much as he could.

---

My Solution:

First I changed the cables from DVI dual-link to DVI. The dvi cable must be connected to the motherboard. Then I could finally see something on boot. If you see a black screen try to press enter since grub might be on. Then you should see a little _ blinking on the top left side of your screen. Once you let it blink for ~ 30 seconds you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and enter the terminal (tty). From there login and enter:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-XXX
```

Where XXX is comes your driver version.

For instance I had the NVIDIA GeForce 346.59 drivers so I had to enter

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-346
```

then reboot with the cable connected to the GPU again. It should no longer show the error above and will boot back into Ubuntu.

EDIT:

If you installed the drivers from software & packages and not from a command line there might be a slight difference!

you can always check all nvidia packages by typing:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

you might find something like this:

```
nvidia-xxx-update
```

to remove that use the purge command above but instead of `nvidia-xxx` use the one you can find by using

```
 dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Dell  4700. 
I booted with an old kernel 3.16 and then installed a 4.0 kernel :

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.0.0*.deb linux-image-4.0.0*.deb
sudo reboot
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone stuck at ACPI-PPC probe failed and cant even get past that, I have another solution. This is often a result after installing the 340 drivers. To fix that do the following:

Grab a ubuntu live cd and boot from it as `*try ubuntu*`

then open the terminal inside it and make yourself root with:

```
sudo -i
```

then make sure you mount your disk with ubuntu or the drivers installed on.

to find that out what your partition is type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

then once you got the partition type in the following

```
 sudo mount /dev/xxx /mnt
```

where xxx is comes the partition like for example `sda1` or `sdb2` or `sdb1` or `sdb2`

in my case it was:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

but most likely it will be `sda1` since allot of people have only one hard disk

then type in:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

once thats done you have full access to modify your disk using the terminal.

beware that you can leave out `sudo` if you typed in `sudo -i` on the beginning

now type in this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

if you have found your driver version/name you can remove with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-XXX
```

where xxx is comes your driver version. For example if we want to remove the 340.52 driver :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-340
```

to remove EVERY package with Nvidia written on it, use:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

now you can reboot again and enjoy ubuntu with sadly no good gpu drivers tough :/

Comment: You can go in a root terminal by choosing "advanced options for Ubuntu" in Grub and then "root terminal", this is a lot faster than booting on a live cd.

Comment: Maybe, but its read-and write mode only, or can you do smth. like sudo mount /dev/xxx /mnt?.

Comment: Honestly I don't know if you cant use mount, I think you can. But anyway you don't need it since this is booting as root on the correct partition. Basically this is doing a boot without graphical interface.

Comment: You saved me. I wish I could give multiple upvotes

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing graphics issues it may be related to this bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346-updates/+bug/1454817

However please read the following for further explanation of these messages.

> ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219

These are two separate messages

> ACPI PPC Probe failed.
>
> Starting version 219

The first is related to a new ACPI interface PCC (Platform Communication Channel) https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/mailbox/pcc.c

Which is defined by UEFI http://www.uefi.org/ACPIv5.1

@Nostromov above pointed out the second is related to **systemd** the program start process manager for Ubuntu 15.04 and above the current version of systemd is 219 so the message **Starting version 219** is just stating the boot process has begun. Noted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1432171

These messages are return prints of mutually exclusive events, they are not related to each other nor are they directly related to the Nvidia graphics issue.

You can see these messages without having any nvidia driver issues.  Please do not assume you have a driver issue if you see these messages. Your PC may boot to the desktop after seeing one or both of them.

You may see this in your output of **journalctl**

> sodu journalctl
>
> Aug 16 23:10:55 x kernel: **PCCT header not found.**
>
> Aug 16 23:10:55 x kernel: **ACPI PCC probe failed.**

These are the returns if the code does not find the ACPI interface which only some very new devices have or if it actually fails to read/write to the interface if it is present.  The code was written for upstream releases.  If you read the emails in the filed bugs below you will find information that supports my statements and you can read the return messages in the code itself in the github link above.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.power-management.general/56400
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.acpi.devel/73411

I hope this helps to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

Have same message and similar problem but... My ASUS G51J does not get stuck on this. I can log in and work with 15.04. So in my case DVI connection should have no bearing on this. I did have login loop issue but purge nvidia-* without anything else lead me to successful login in 640/480 mode. Then in software & update under additional drivers I did install nvidia 340.76.
So far it works for me.
BTW. During upgrade from 14.10 I did remove all obsolete/not used/not needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

well fail after fail i gave up on ubuntu and went back to kali...when i realized in setting up nvidia there with cuda a interesting article es

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

lspci | grep VGA
```

and found i was `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation gtx760`
and followed his lead

```
nvidia-xconfig
vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and changed the way he did to what your device is

looks like

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection
```

and changed to

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:01:00:0"
EndSection
```

reboot and 
working 100% as i am total noob and have no idea what i did just know it works one day hope to learn terminal and what i did... many thanks to blacMORE  ... hope it helps others tho due to i hate microsoft and ubuntu i must learn to get away from them,

Answer (score 0):

I also have nvidia, and this issue started when I switched primary gpu interface to PCI Express (from on-board graphics). 
Switching back to onboard as primary care interface in UEFI BIOS (North bridge IIRC) fixed the issue for me. I get no boot messages, only black screen, but I haven't set the no modeset flag yet, and my Ubuntu works with latest nvidia drivers.