# Why wont steam launch? Please help! Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam

Steam wont launch, i get this message

```
crazyfrog@crazyfrog-desktop:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: if using nvidia maybe the same as here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/615149/nvidia-drivers-on-15-04-kernel-3-19-stalling-system-load

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install openGL:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this two scripts:

[Boot guru script in users](https://app.box.com/s/ke26lsjh90yljg3yft0u)

[IOSYS Guru script in users](https://app.box.com/s/l2qpni42c2omaq4zd1gc)

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: When linking external pages, it is required that you put an overview of those pages in your answer, FYI.