# I'm new to Ubuntu. Am I doing something wrong wrong with steam?

Tags: drivers, steam

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have nvidia card ?

Comment: Assuming you are using an nVidia card you may need to update to Linux kernel 4.0. Refer to this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/615603/143396

Comment: possible duplicate of [nVidia drivers on 15.04 kernel 3.19 stalling system load](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615149/nvidia-drivers-on-15-04-kernel-3-19-stalling-system-load)