# Installing 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, usb-installation

I'm trying to install 14.04.3 onto a former Vista PC, downloading from U's website, using Unetbootin 613.exe with 8GB USB2.0 flash drive. PC is Advent, 2GB RAM, 250 GB hard disc, Nvidia Geforce 7300LE.
After installing, it shows error "ACPI PCC probe failed" and either 0:663712 or 4.991714. After the initial splash screen, the screen goes blank. The screen is fine, as it works OK on another PC.

Comment: Also take a look [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia).

Comment: Mitch, thanks for your prompt reply. Am studying the other topics, if I can understand them! Thanks anyway. Proves the usefulness of Askubuntu.