# "Try Ubuntu" option for 14.04 stops loading?

Tags: boot

I have Dell 7910 Tower with Xeon Processor.

The "try Ubuntu" stops booting after giving the following messages:

```
[ 0.082479] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[ 4.933464] ACPI PCC Probe failed.
```

Internet search none of these is the cause of stopping ubuntu from booting?

Any advice what is causing this or how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read it's display driver related.  It should boot after a while, but if it doesn't, then try installing the full OS onto your hard disk, and then install the correct GPU drivers for your card.

Also, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia).

You can also try adding the `nomodeset` option during bootup if nothing else works.

Comment: Not familiar with that card, but it's worth trying.  You can always install to an external hard drive or USB stick if you don't want to wipe your current OS.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this. I check to see if it is possible to install Ubuntu. I have a Quadro M6000 on this machine. My concern is that if "try ubuntu" doesn't work, it is not going to boot when I install it. Well, I give it a try and let you know. Thank you again.

Comment: If it doesn't boot to the GUI, you can always use the Text Only interface.

Comment: Oh, I have the Ubuntu on USB bootable flash drive. It is going to be a dual boot machine, since I have windows on it too. But I have set aside about 900GB unpartitioned drive ready for Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, then go ahead and install

Comment: BTW, I just looked up that card.  Jaw dropping.

Comment: I tried installing Ubuntu. Same thing. It starts booting and then produces those two lines and then nothing. Get stalled there.

Comment: Try starting it up and letting it sit there for a week or two.  If it doesn't move forwards, try a different version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, didn't waited for a week. But tried 14.04.3 and let it run over night. No luck. Also tried 15.10 (though waited only few minutes) same issue except the ACPI PCC line did not show up.

Comment: Ok, Added "nomodeset" to the boot options and it works just fine now. Although, when it boots the wired internet connection seems not working.

Comment: That's a separate issue and I'd recommend you ask another question.

Comment: I'll add the `nomodeset` option to my answer so you can accept it.