# I just installed ubuntu and deleted windows 8, now It does not work. I tried using boot-repair but still does not work

Tags: boot-repair

My laptop is a toshiba satellite C55.

Here is the url for the boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13089017/

Comment: Do you mean that you removed windows during the Ubuntu installation? Or afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only Ubuntu (and no Windows), then the best option is to do a clean install and during the install wipe (format) the entire hard disk..

That way you have a clean system and rest of the things will work fine

Comment: Varun, thank you for replying.

I did the clean install and wiped the entire disk. I used the boot-repair, and when I rebooted I made sure the boot order was correct (Hard-disk then usb).

Without the usb, I was able to boot but then it went to a black screen and i get the error "ACPI PCC probe failed".Disk check ensures and then i am dropped to root terminal screen.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is quite tricky to solve from what I've seen. If you changed your display driver(from X.Org Nouveau) to NVIDIA you will need to do the following:

1. Use the X.Org Nouveau display driver (by purging the Nvidia binary drivers as described in other answers). The drawback is that it will impact the graphics performance which is better with an official Nvidia driver.
2. Install the Nvidia driver and boot with the 'nomodeset' flag. To do this, configure Grub as described in the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383636/12-04-3-can-start-only-after-press-resume-in-rescue-mode-every-boot-proble).

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia)

Otherwise, it could be a BIOS setting, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed).

Then again, a clean install of Ubuntu is supposed to work.