# Installing Nvidia driver crash system after restart. ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am new to Linux and need some help, because I always fail to install Nvidia drivers.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. After that I wanted to install Nvidia drivers, so I went to `Software & Updates>Additional Drivers` and choose "**Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 352.63 from nvidia-352(proprietary, tested)**" option. Everything seems to work, until I restart the PC. When I restart the PC it just loads black screen with this message "**[ 0.472102] ACPI PCC probe failed**" and it can't load to desktop.

here is an image:

[image]

I tried with all the suggested Nvidia drivers from Additional Drivers and same problem appears with all of them. After every Nvidia driver install I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 because I couldn't load the OS.

I tried to fix it by doing

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
Change line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
Ctrl-X, press Y and then Enter to save and exit.
sudo update-grub
```

It didn't work. All it did was that the message [ 0.472102] ACPI PCC probe failed didn't appear anymore and it was just black screen with a blinking line.

also tried

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub and changed
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
sudo update-grub2
```

it didn't work also.

here is some hardware of my PC in case you need it:

Motherboard: Asrock Z77 Extreme 3

CPU: Intelcore - i5 3570k

GPU: Asus Nvidia GTX 760 OC.

Right now I am using the default driver X.Org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proprietary nvidia driver should be used without KMS. You have to edit the /etc/default/grub file, use your favourite text editor (vi, nano, gedit, etc.):

sudo vi /etc/default/grub

Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" line to the following:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Save the file, then run sudo update-grub Then reboot, and it should work.

If it still doesn't solve it, then remove also "quiet splash" from the previous line, and again sudo update-grub. (This will disable the graphical boot screen.)

The recovery booting did work, because the recovery menu entry had the nomodeset parameter.
**source:** [ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219 NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia/613989#613989)

Comment: No its fine. If it worked for you please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you. Now after I restart PC, the message "ACPI PPC Probe failed" appear for a few seconds and the system continues to boot until it reaches the desktop.

Should I worry that this message still appears for a few seconds ?