# Grub works but ubuntu wont start. [0.820741] ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, acpi

So Im first time user, dual booting w/W7. installation went good with updates and everything then it needed to restart to finish installation. when it did no grub, no logo appeared jut the purple screen. Restarted again grub showed chose Ubuntu but it gave me this error message every time I choose ubuntu.

```
[   0.842363] ACPI PCC probe failed
```

and when in advanced mode

```
[   0.820741] ACPI PCC probe failed
```

system info

```
HP pavalion dv6. 
win7x64. BIOS. 
intel(R) Core(TM)i7-2670QM CPU.
Radeon (TM) HD 7690M XT
```

tell me if you need more system info. 
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia